# Are the Udacity forums part of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, clone

I was looking at [forums.udacity.com](http://forums.udacity.com), and noticed that the badge system and user system are much like all Stack Exchange sites.

However, there is no mention of that site being part of Stack Exchange anywhere, and the home page looks much different than Stack Exchange's.

Is this site really part of Stack Exchange? Or do they just look similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope. It's a [clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/213671), or a site that looks similar, but is not part of the Stack Exchange network. All SE sites are under the `stackexchange.com` domain name.

The following sites have their own domain name because they are older:

- [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/)
- [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)

There is also [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/), a special exception that was formed because of a partnership between Ubuntu and Stack Exchange. However, this sort of relationship does not happen anymore (there was a dedicated facebook dev site, but that was phased out). You have to go through [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to get a site approved.

And, there is [MathOverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/), which was started as an SE 1.0 site in September 2009. It eventually joined the network in June 2013, yet it is still owned by the independent entity MathOverflow and its presence in the network is governed by an individual agreement.

Plus, they have double diamond users. What does that even mean???

Comment: SE 1.0 sites had double-diamond users too; they were admins. Most recently seen on pre-migration MathOverflow.

Comment: There are more SE sites not under stackexchange.com, e.g., mathoverflow.net.

Comment: @KevinSayHi: Actually, MathOverflow was (not-so-)recently inaugurated into the SE network.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That is true, but I think that Kevin was referring to the fact that mathoverflow.net is not a subdomain of stackexchange.com.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Oh I should have said "... not under *the domain name* stackexchange.com" to clear any ambiguity (it should have been clear from context, though).

Comment: @KevinSayHi There was no ambiguity. MathOverflow's status as part of StackExchange but not but not under stackexchange.com was quite clear. There are serverfault and superuser as well.

Comment: @FeralOink Of course there's no ambiguity in the *fact*. I mean, BoltClock's a Unicorn might have interpreted my comment as MathOverflow is not under the supervision of StackExchange.

Comment: You said, "All SE sites are under the stackexchange.com domain name (besides SO, SF, SU, and AU)". What is AU?

Comment: @FeralOink, [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), the site for the Ubuntu distribution of Linux.

Comment: The information given here regarding MO is possibly ambigous. mathoverflow.net is at the moment part of the Stack Exchange network. Thus while in some sense it is true that MathOverflow is part of Stack Exchange (the site is part of the network), in another sense it is however *not* true, as [MathOverflow is an independent nonprofit nonstock corporation in the state of Delaware](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow) and not part of Stack Exchange, Inc.  I would not mention it in parallel with S[OFU]; it is also more a special case site like AU.

Comment: @quid, agreed. I honestly don't know anything about MathOverflow, visited it for the first time today. I just took the information from BoltClock. If you want to edit the question, go for it.